# How can I make ports forwarded via AWS SSM available to connections not originating from localhost?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, portforwarding, aws-session-manager

I am using AWS CLI in a Docker container to open a port forwarding session to a remote host via AWS SSM on an EC2 instance. So that I can access the port from outside of the Docker container, I am mapping it in Docker so that it is available on my own host.

The issue now is that any connection to this port from outside of the Docker container is immediately closed. My guess is that this is due to safeguards in the port forwarding session, which will allow connections to the forwarded port only from `localhost`. However, when I am accessing the port from my host machine, it will not show up as `localhost` and the connection is immediately terminated.

How can I configure the port forwarding session so that I can also create connections to this port that do not originate from `localhost`?

I have already had a look at the SSM document `AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost` to see if I can modify this. However, I could not find documentation that would give me the possible values for `properties.type`, which I assume is the culprit for only accepting connections from `localhost`.

---

Full content of the `AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost` SSM document:

```
{
  "schemaVersion": "1.0",
  "description": "Document to start port forwarding session over Session Manager to remote host",
  "sessionType": "Port",
  "parameters": {
    "portNumber": {
      "type": "String",
      "description": "(Optional) Port number of the server on the instance",
      "allowedPattern": "^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])$",
      "default": "80"
    },
    "localPortNumber": {
      "type": "String",
      "description": "(Optional) Port number on local machine to forward traffic to. An open port is chosen at run-time if not provided",
      "allowedPattern": "^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])$",
      "default": "0"
    },
    "host": {
      "type": "String",
      "description": "(Optional) Hostname or IP address of the destination server",
      "allowedPattern": "^[^,$^&\\(\\)!;'\"<>\\`{}\\[\\]\\|#=]{3,}$",
      "default": "localhost"
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "portNumber": "{{ portNumber }}",
    "type": "LocalPortForwarding",
    "localPortNumber": "{{ localPortNumber }}",
    "host": "{{ host }}"
  }
}
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM amazon/aws-cli

RUN curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/session-manager-downloads/plugin/latest/linux_64bit/session-manager-plugin.rpm" -o "session-manager-plugin.rpm" && yum install -y ./session-manager-plugin.rpm && yum install -y telnet
```

Docker command:

```
docker run \
  --rm \
  -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY -e AWS_SESSION_TOKEN \
  -p 5432:5432 \
  -ti \
  awscli-ssm \
  ssm start-session \
    --target <my-ec2-instance-id> \
    --region <my-region> \
    --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost \
    --parameters '{"host":["<my-rds-host>.rds.amazonaws.com"],"portNumber":["5432"], "localPortNumber":["5432"]}'
```

When running `telnet localhost 5432` in the Docker container, connection remains open:

```
bash-4.2# telnet localhost 5432
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

When running `telnet localhost 5432` from outside of the Docker container, connection is closed immediately:

```
chris@chris-machine:~$ telnet localhost 5432
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a fix, but at least a workaround: Create a local tunnel inside the Docker container, thereby making it look to AWS like the connection is coming from `localhost`.

---

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM amazon/aws-cli

RUN curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/session-manager-downloads/plugin/latest/linux_64bit/session-manager-plugin.rpm" -o "session-manager-plugin.rpm" && yum install -y ./session-manager-plugin.rpm
RUN yum install -y socat
```

Build it: `docker build . -t awscli-ssm`

Run it (note the different port supplied to `-p`):

```
docker run \
  --rm \
  -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY -e AWS_SESSION_TOKEN \
  -p 13000:13000 \
  -ti \
  --entrypoint "" \
  awscli-ssm \
  bash -c "socat tcp-listen:13000,reuseaddr,fork tcp:localhost:5432 & \
  aws ssm start-session \
    --target <my-ec2-instance-id> \
    --region <my-region> \
    --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost \
    --parameters '{\"host\":[\"<my-rds-host>.rds.amazonaws.com\"],\"portNumber\":[\"5432\"], \"localPortNumber\":[\"5432\"]}'
```

Your connection is now available outside of the container on `localhost:13000`.